# Silverlight Get actual width of Grid that is set as Auto

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, actualwidth

Say I have a `Grid` whose `Width` is set as `Auto`. Inside this grid I want to put a new grid that is a square. To do this I want the new grid's width and height to be equal. I thought I could just set the `Width` and `Height` to the Parent Grid's `Width`. The problem is, the Parent grid's width is double.NaN since it is set to auto.

My question, is there a way to get the `ActualWidth` of this parent grid, so that I know how wide it is? If not, is there another way to create a Rectangular Grid that fits inside the parent grid?

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the property of `ActualWidth`

```
var width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
```